# RedirectToRoute and status code 302

Tags: symfony4

I'm developing my first project with Symfony 4.1. I have problem with redirectToRoute in function from controller which is used in Twig to rendering the form. Function is correct but after submit the form is an error: An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Error when rendering "http://localhost:8000/pl/contact/agro/" (Status code is 302)." Where can I search solution for this problem ? Maybe I can't use redirectToRoute function in this action without route header ?

**My ContactController**

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function renderForm(Request $request, $currentBrand)
    {
        $formData = new ContactEmail();
```

`$form = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $formData);
    $formSecond = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $formData);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $formSecond->handleRequest($request);

    $sendFlag = false;
    $sendFlagSecond = false;

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $formData = $form->getData();
        $formData->setIpAddress($request->getClientIp());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($formData);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('main_page_contact', [
            'slugBrand' => $currentBrand->getSlugName(),
        ]);

    } else if ($formSecond->isSubmitted() && $formSecond->isValid()) {
        $formData = $formSecond->getData();
        $formData->setIpAddress($request->getClientIp());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($formData);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('main_page_contact', [
            'slugBrand' => $currentBrand->getSlugName(),
        ]);
    }


        return $this->render('main_page/widget/contact/contact-form.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'formSecond' => $formSecond->createView(),
            'wasSent' => $sendFlag,
            'wasSentSecond' => $sendFlagSecond,
        ]);
    }
}`

**The form is rendering by below code from Twig:**

render(controller('App\Controller\MainPage\ContactController::renderForm', {'request': app.request, 'currentBrand': currentBrand})) }}

Thanks for answers!

Comment: what's up with the `if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) ` and  `else if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())`. Are those not the same?

Comment: You'r right, in code was mistake, should be **formSecond**. I edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution. RedirectToRoute should be in this same method where is @Route which is called by redirectToRoute. It looks everythink works.

```
/**
* @Route("/{_locale}/contact/{slugBrand}/", name="main_page_contact")
*/
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request, $slugBrand)
    {
        $currentBrand = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Brand::class)
            ->getOneOrNullVisibleBySlugName($slugBrand);
```

`if (is_null($currentBrand)) {
        return new Response('Brak marki');
    }

    $formData = new ContactEmail();

    $form = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $formData);
    $formSecond = $this->createForm(ContactFormType::class, $formData);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    $formSecond->handleRequest($request);

    $sendFlag = false;
    $sendFlagSecond = false;

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $formData = $form->getData();
            $formData->setIpAddress($request->getClientIp());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($formData);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('main_page_contact', [
            'slugBrand' => $currentBrand->getSlugName()]);

        } else if ($formSecond->isSubmitted() && $formSecond->isValid()) {
            $formData = $formSecond->getData();
            $formData->setIpAddress($request->getClientIp());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($formData);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('main_page_contact', [
            'slugBrand' => $currentBrand->getSlugName()]);
    }
    return $this->render('main_page/widget/contact/contact-form.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'formSecond' => $formSecond->createView(),
        'wasSent' => $sendFlag,
        'wasSentSecond' => $sendFlagSecond,
        'currentBrand' => $currentBrand,
        'slugBrand' => $slugBrand,
        'shared' => $this->getAllSharedDataForLayout(),
    ]);
}`